# Implementing the Shih-Wu Euclidean distance transform: what is R(p) used for?

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing

I'm attempting to implement the [Shih-Wu distance transform](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Download/IAD/Shih_Wu_04.pdf) algorithm, as described on page 5 of [the pdf](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Download/IAD/Shih_Wu_04.pdf). It looks fairly simple but I'm hampered by my limited math (or possibly my reading comprehension ability).

I think I have it all except for one question:

In the algorithm, how is `R(p)` used? It is meticulously calculated using `h(p,q)` and `G(p,q)`, and then appears not to be used anywhere.

I'm sure it's explained somewhere in the proof, but the math is opaque to me, and I don't see R mentioned in the lead-in to the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definitions on page 4 it says:

> R(p): The relative-coordinates vector R(p) = (Rx, Ry) of pixel p,
>   which records the horizontal and vertical pixel-distances between p
>   and the closest background pixel. It is initialized as all (0,0). Note
>   that, Rx(p) and Ry(p) indicate the horizontal and vertical
>   pixel-distances, respectively.

At every pixel, the algorithm calculates h() using the R values already saved in the neighboring pixels, and then saves the R value for that pixel so that it can be used in the calculations for the next pixel.

Comment: It sure does - but then what is done with it? The algorithm doesn't seem to address how it's used once it's calculated.

Comment: Ahh, so R(q) is actually the value of R(p) under the location of q in the kernel? (Wasn't my downvote, btw)